# General Message / Function fired on Dialog destruction?

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

I'm looking for a method or message that is **always** fired when an MFC Dialog (`CDialog` or `CDialogEx`) is getting destroyed.

I found the following messages which seem cause a dialogs destruction:

- WM_DESTROY
- WM_CLOSE
- WM_QUIT (not only for dialogs but to quit from the main message loop which causes destruction as well)

Together with those inheritable function which get called when a dialog closes **but not always**:

- `OnOk()`
- `OnCancel()`

And I'm unsure about `OnFinalRelease()` as it seems to be something for OLE controls.

**Is there a message or method *always* called or fired when a dialog gets destructed?** I need to do some final heap cleanup on the destruction of my dialog instance.

Comment: Why a message?  You are using a C++ wrapper class, use the destructor.

Comment: I did that before and ended up having access violations because GDI+ was shut down at the point where destructors are being called. Many destructors of GDI+ objects use GDI+ calls in their destructors. Hence I can't delete a resource that was using GDI+ there. I need something that happens before the destruction of the wrapper class.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: It looks like you are not familiar with MFC Dialogs. They are not really designed for clean ups and when using heap together with GDI+ the one or the other attachment to dialog destroying methods are necessary. Anyw. I found an answer in the answers below. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override CDialogEx::PostNcDestroy (inherited from CWnd).  This is always called by the framework after it is done destroying the window. [CWnd::PostNcDestroy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk933a19.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

CDialog::OnClose should be called before all the window objects gets destroyed, while CDialog::OnDestroy should be called once they are already destroyed (its opposite to CDialog::OnCreate). To make sure this is how it works in you case you can use Spy++ to see what messages are comming.

Instead of relying on windows messages, I would suggest to wrap whatever resoures you are using into some [RAII](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization) idiom. This might be a std::unique_ptr or some specialized class. The will protect you against uncaught exceptions or missing windows messages.